# WebService type confusion

Tags: f#, unit-type

I am using [this template](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/279345a4-f189-4d1f-98fe-6b1af322d164) to create a web service.

Here is a Web Service Contract I am using:

```
[<ServiceContract>]
type ISimpleService =
    [<OperationContract>]
    abstract GetItems: value:int -> Item[]
    [<OperationContract>]
    abstract InsertItem: composite:Item -> int
```

1. Where can I find `value` and `composite` description? Is it language feature or something else?
2. I want to GetItem method doesn't have any imput parameters and InsertItem doesn't return the value (void).  Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `value` and `composite` symbols in the code sample are just names of the parameters. This pretty much corresponds to the following C# interface:

```cs
[ServiceContract]
interface ISimpleService {
  [OperationContract]
  Item[] GetItems(int value);
  [OperationContract]
  int InsertItem(Item composite);
}
```

If you want to change the definition so that `InsertItem` does not return anything and `GetItem` does not take anything, you need to change their return and input types to `unit`:

```
[<ServiceContract>]
type ISimpleService =
    [<OperationContract>]
    abstract GetItems: unit -> Item[]
    [<OperationContract>]
    abstract InsertItem: composite:Item -> unit
```

The `unit` type (roughly) corresponds to `void` in C# when used as a return type and this is also how it will be compiled. When used as input, `unit` corresponds to an empty parameter list (and it is compiled as such).

This may sound confusing, but the `unit` type is an F# type with just one value written as `()`, so when you call `foo()`, you are actually passing the value of type `unit` as an argument. This takes some time getting used to, but it makes the language elegantly simple.